# I need to process the action when I click on the notification button, but how do I not close the system panel? The intent is processed in the Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, service, notifications

At the moment, there is some action that is being processed in the activity, which is immediately closed. (finish()). I need the message to close when clicking on the action button, but not the system panel (I need it NOT to COLLAPSE). As, for example, in a Telegram, when you click on the "mark as read" button. How to do it? And is it possible? Maybe you shouldn't use activity to process the intent? Examples of how everything should work:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

As I wrote before - at this point some action happens, an intent is created, which is processed in an activity that closes immediately. (finish()). I was not advised to use Services or Broadcast Receivers, but I came to the conclusion that this is a feature when using PendingIntent.getActivity.